# GTKAda hello world

Tags: ada, gtkada

I am having linking errors trying to run the gtkada sample program that comes with GPS.

Link
   [link]         main.adb
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so: undefined reference to `pango_fc_font_map_config_changed'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gprbuild: link of main.adb failed
[2018-07-19 09:39:45] process exited with status 4, 100% (8/8), elapsed time: 01.05s

Is there a way to see what library paths GPS is searching?

Thanks,

Comment: Well, the problem is not that a required library is not found. The problem is that a required library is not linked against. So I am not sure how seeing the library paths GPS (in fact, GPRBuild) is searching will help you. Libraries that are linked against are always explicitly specified and never just taken because they happen to exist in some path.

Answer (score 0):

In *Project/Build/Switches/Ada Linker*, add (in the summary line at the bottom of the panel)

```
-v -Wl,-v
```

(the `-v` is a switch to `gnatbind`, the `-Wl,-v` is a switch to the underlying linker. You may only need the latter)